# Scriplet not validating correctly

Tags: java, validation, jsp

I would like to do a conditional that checks if the session ID saved in a txt file is the same as the session ID passed as a URL parameter. If they are the same write a different value to file and continue with the JSP page display, otherwise redirect to the name_login.jsp page. However, my code always seem to redirect, even though I verified both values are the same.

```
<%

    String txtFilePath = "C:/oc/tomcat/webapps/foo.txt";
    //String txtFilePath2 = "C:/oc/tomcat/webapps/foo2.txt";
    String reset_access="ccsae";
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(txtFilePath));
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(txtFilePath));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;

    while((line = reader.readLine())!= null){
        sb.append(line+"\n");
    }
    String access_status= sb.toString(); 
    String url_status= (String)request.getParameter("session");

    if (access_status!= url_status){

        String redirectURL = "https://url/www/name_login.php";
                    response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
    }

    writer.write(reset_access);     
    writer.close();



%>
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

This is another way to check equality of string:

```
if(access_status.compareTo(url_status)!=0) {
    String redirectURL = "https://url/www/name_login.php";
    response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

use String.equals() method for string comparison, like this

```
if (!access_status.equals(url_status)){
.....your code here
}
```

Comment: It is still redirecting when it should be displaying the rest of the page. Not sure why.

Comment: 1-Try to log both variables content to check if they similar. 2- Trim both variables before comparison so extra spaces won't change the result

Answer (score 0):

The following code is working correctly. I had to separate the portion that writes a reset code to the file. Still not sure why, it works this way, but it works.

```
<%
   String txtFilePath = "C:/oc/tomcat/webapps/foo.txt";
    String txtFilePath2 = "C:/oc/tomcat/webapps/foo2.txt";
    String reset_access="ccsae";

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(txtFilePath));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;

    while((line = reader.readLine())!= null){
        sb.append(line+"\n");
        //sb.append(line);
    }
    String access_status= sb.toString().trim(); 
    String url_status= request.getParameter("session").toString();
    if (access_status =="" || access_status.isEmpty()){
        access_status="not valid";
    }

    if (!access_status.equals(url_status)){

        String redirectURL = "https://url/www/name_login.php";
                    response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
    }




%>
<%
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(txtFilePath));

    writer.write(reset_access)

    writer.close();

%>
```